# Определить класс, вызвавший метод. Python, наследование

Tags: python

```
class a :
    def m1() :
        print(__class__.__name__)

class b(a) :
    pass

a.m1() # a
b.m1() # a
```

А как получить имя класса, который вызвал метод ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если надо определять имя класса для экземпляров, то код должен быть следующим:

```
class A:
    def m1(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)


class B(A):
    pass


a = A()
b = B()
a.m1()
b.m1()
```

Если же Вам действительно нужно работать без создания экземпляров, то можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def m1(cls):
        print(cls.__name__)


class B(A):
    pass


A.m1()
B.m1()
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное !